# When you type a search term in copy mode, is there a way to erase the search term with something like CTRL-U?

Tags: tmux

I enter into copy mode and do a search of the tmux window buffer with `/`. This works great, except when I want to do a second search, the original search term appears at the search prompt and I have to erase it by pressing and holding down the DELETE key. CTRL-U doesn't seem to clear the line. Is there a faster way to clear the search term than DELETE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention using `/` for searching, I will assume you are using vi-mode keys. The default `vi-edit` key table does not bind C-u (it is bound to `delete-line` in the `emacs-edit` key table).

You can bind it manually (e.g. in your `.tmux.conf`, or after <prefix>`:`):

```
bind-key -t vi-edit C-u delete-line
```